# What can be said about compact embedded exact Lagrangians in the generalized pair of pants?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, floer-homology

What can be said about compact embedded exact Lagrangians in the $n$-dimensional generalized pair of pants e.g. the hypersurface in $(\mathbb{C}^*)^{n+1}$ defined by the equation:

$$ 1+\Sigma_i z_i = 0 $$

By exact, I mean with respect to the standard Liouville structure coming from being an affine variety. For example, can we provide restrictions on their homotopy type? In his thesis, Sheridan has constructed a very interesting immersed Lagrangian sphere $L$ using tropical geometry and computed the $A_\infty$ algebra $HF^*(L,L)$, where $HF^*$ is the Floer cohomology. But I cannot see any obvious embedded exact Lagrangians in there (EDIT: As Zack points out below there are some very natural exact Lagrangian tori in the pair of pants coming from the fact that there are natural Liouville subdomains isomorphic to $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$). Because the classification of real surfaces is so explicit, the case $n=2$ may be the most interesting to consider. Of course if one assumes a sufficiently strong version of homological mirror symmetry, it should be possible to say something. But I am more interested in what can be deduced using "standard techniques."

Somewhat more speculatively, are there any compact embedded exact Lagrangians which are not tori in the generalized pair of pants?

Comment: If nothing else, it has $n+2$ Liouville subdomains isomorphic to $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$, each of which contains an exact Lagrangian torus.

Comment: Maybe it's helpful to notice that it is expected that there is an $A_\infty$-functor from the Fukaya category of the pair of pants to the Fukaya category of $(\mathbb{C}^\ast)^{n+1}\times\mathbb{C}$ given by  Lagrangian correspondence.

Comment: That doesn't seem quite right ... $Fuk((\mathbb{C}^*)^{n+1} \times \mathbb{C})$ should be empty (maybe equip it with some sort of partial-wrapping ?). There's some similar construction in work of Smith and Abouzaid, Auroux, Katzarkov which involves a blowup of $(\mathbb{C}^*)^{n+1} \times \mathbb{C}$ (but does not seem simpler than working with the hypersurface itself).